# SQL Server: como criar range de valores baseado numa coluna com valores monetários

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Olá, comunidade!

Eu preciso de uma consulta SQL com os valores de um campo de tabela do SQL Server 2012 mostrados como distribuição de frequência.

Digamos que eu tenha, hoje, o campo Vendas (em R$), tipo float.

A menor venda registrada foi de R$ 0,01 e a maior de R$ 1.000.345,23.

O detalhe é que eu nunca vou saber qual a maior e qual a menor venda.

São centenas de vendas. Eu quero retornar as frequências de classe. Cada classe terá um range de R$ 100.000,00.

Então meus resultado teriam que vir em forma de uma distribuição de frequência.

Assim,

A tabela SQL Server 2012 carrega os valores de venda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A consulta traz os valores distribuídos em range:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que uma coisa mais ou menos assim resolve, se quiser agrupar por 0-9,10-99,100-999, etc: `GROUP BY FLOOR( LOG(  valor ) / LOG( 10 ) + 1 )`. Se quiser apenas dividindo por 1000000, 2000000 etc bastaria `GROUP BY FLOOR( valor / 1000000  )`.

Comment: A hora que o SQL Fiddle resolver funcionar eu posto mais completo, em forma de resposta.

Comment: T-SQL tem LOG10( valor ) também...

Comment: Consegui, @Bacco! Com sua ajuda, claro!!! Na verdade, cheguei a uma página que explica tudo direitinho: http://sqlsunday.com/2014/09/14/histogram-in-t-sql/. Eu vou postar o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis uma solução que agrupa por quantidades de 1.00 a 9.99, 10.00 a 99.99, 100.00 a 999.99 e assim sucessivamente:

```
SELECT   POWER( 10, FLOOR( LOG10( valor ) + 1 ) ) - .01 AS Teto,
         COUNT(*) AS Quantidade
FROM     valores
GROUP BY FLOOR( LOG10( valor ) + 1 )
ORDER BY Teto;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45727/16)**.

O importante aqui é o `FLOOR( LOG10( valor ) )` para agrupar o número de casas, as variações disto são detalhes.

Se mudar a informação para `GROUP BY FLOOR( valor / 1000 )`, por exemplo, a fórmula fica escalonada linearmente (basta ajustar o número de zeros de acordo com a escala desejada)

Aqui tem um **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a1e2/1)** com a versão linear.

**Nota**: As linhas do `AS Base` `AS Teto` são mera formatação para display e conferência de dados. Muito provavelmente uma mensagem `De 1 a 9.99` fica melhor, e mais fácil de ser mostrada na aplicação, bastando obter uma coluna com a mesma fórmula do `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Muito mais eficiente do que o que eu tinha postado. Por eficiente, na minha leiguice com SQL, eu quero dizer que é um código pequeno e que cumpre o papel a que se destina. Eu só postei o outro código porque não tinha visto a sua resposta ainda, mas de qualquer forma taí pra documentar. Obrigado mais uma vez!!!

Comment: @JohnDoe Postei a 2a versão, linear, e mexi nas colunas da 1a para mostrar melhor a faixa de ação. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Esse ficou bem preciso!!! Muito bom mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Preferi a versão marcada como resposta!

**ORIGINAL**

Essa é a solução que me atende. Consegui graças à ajuda do @Bacco, que me fez chegar a [este link](http://sqlsunday.com/2014/09/14/histogram-in-t-sql/), no blog de Daniel Hutmacher.

```html
DECLARE @intervalo numeric(38, 18), --- amplitude de cada classe
        @min numeric(38, 18), --- menor valor da tabela
        @max numeric(38, 18), --- maior valor da tabela
        @niveis smallint=7; --- numero de classes

--- pega os valores maximos e minimos usando MIN(), MAX() e conta as linhas da tabela COUNT()
SELECT @max=MAX(vendas),
       @min=MIN(vendas)
FROM [meuBancoDeDados].[dbo].[minhaTabelaDeValores];

--- Calcula cada intervalo de classe
SET @intervalo=(@max-@min)/@niveis;

SELECT @min+@intervalo*FLOOR(vendas/@intervalo) AS fromValue,
       @min+@intervalo*FLOOR(vandas/@intervalo)+@intervalo AS toValue,
       COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM (
      SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(vendas, @max), @max-0.5*@intervalo)-@min AS vendas
      FROM [meuBancoDeDados].[dbo].[minhaTabelaDeValores]
      ) AS sub
GROUP BY FLOOR(vendas/@intervalo)
ORDER BY FLOOR(vendas/@intervalo);
```